# Как, используя perl, сохранить результат sql-запроса в файл?

Tags: perl, mysql

Скрипт должен делать следующее:

- пользователь вводит с клавиатуры запрос (это знаю)
- perl толкает запрос в mysql (тоже знаю)
- mysql выполняет запрос - и вот тут мне нужно как-то сохранить результат `SELECT`а в файл построчно (вот об этом и спрашиваю).

Answer (score 2):

Собственно программа, назовем ее mysql.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w --

use warnings;
use strict;

use DBI;

my $DSN = "DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost";

sub main {
    my $sql = $ARGV[0];
    my $dbh = DBI->connect(
        $DSN,
        undef,
        undef,
        {
            RaiseError => 1,
            AutoCommit => 0
        }
    ) or die "Connect error: " . $DBI::errstr;
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql ) or die "Prepare error: " . $dbh->errstr;

    $sth->execute or die "Execute error: " . $dbh->errstr;

    print join("\t", @{ $sth->{NAME} } ), "\n";
    while ( my $row = $sth->fetch ) {
        print join("\t", map { defined($_) ? $_ : 'NULL'} @{ $row  }), "\n";
    }
    $sth->finish;
    $dbh->disconnect;
}

&main;

1;

__END__
```

Выполняет запросы к базе данных test на localhost, и выводит результаты на stdout, поля разделяются символом табуляции, используем так:

```
% ./mysql.pl "select * from table" > output.file
```

Если чего непонятно - спрашивай

Comment: Первый ответ - красивый. Только не надо функцию называть main.
Как-то не кошерно.

Comment: Собственно почему нет ?
main - это значение пакета по-умолчанию, и соответственно вызов main::main() - достаточно неплохо выглядит.
Насколько я знаю функция main ни где не зарезервирована и рекомендаций по ее использованию (в отличии от переменных типа $a, $b и т.д.) нету

Comment: Касаемо "кошерности", можно было-бы все сделать правильно, получилось бы что то типа: https://gist.github.com/1269992

Answer (score 2):

sqlsh не нужен — всё делается самим mysql:

```
echo 'SELECT 2*2, 3*3' | mysql # можно добавить -u username -ppassword databasename
```

Выдаёт ответ, в котором по умолчанию поля (столбцы) разделены символом табуляции, а записи (строки) — переводом строки:

```
2*2    3*3
4      9
```

Answer (score 1):

я бы сделал так:
поставил бы sqlsh
и далее

```
sqlsh -d DBI:MYSQL:MYSERVER.DE.COM -u user -p password -i < my_run.sql

содержимое my_run.sql
set multiline on;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI';
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = my_shema;
set log-mode box;
log queries result.txt;
select * from dual;
no log;
exit;
```

и в result.txt видим:

```
|| DUMMY |
| X     |
```

Comment: 1. это супер, спасибо, кстати, а можно так DDL выполнять?
2. но sqlsh это выдает в wiki фицированном формате , с разделителями '|'

Comment: я просто результат в жиру кидаю в вики формате как таблицу